# Remove web page text property

Tags: css, codeigniter

I use `@paper { size :landscape; }` CSS, but how can I remove the side text like page url, number page etc. on print preview page? so the print looks more clean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6uIN.png

Comment: To target, the print use the print media query `@media print {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @media print { 
    @page { 
        margin-top: 0; 
        margin-bottom: 0; 
    } 
    body { 
        padding-top: 72px; 
        padding-bottom: 72px ; 
    } 
}
```

or This could be helpful too:

```
@print { 
    @page :footer { 
        display: none
    } 
  
    @page :header { 
        display: none
    } 
}
```